# What is the canonical name for a function that ensures that an asynchronous task takes at least x time to resolve?

Tags: asynchronous, naming-conventions, convention, canonical-name

Say we have an asynchronous function that may resolve within any duration. However fast it may be, we want to ensure it never resolves before `t` time as passed. To achieve this in a reusable way, we create a function (here in JavaScript):

```js
async function stall(task, minDuration) {
  // Wait until both `task` and `delay(minDuration)` resolves
  // and return the results from `task`
  const results = await Promise.all([task, delay(minDuration)])
  return results[0]
}
```

where `delay()` is a simple function that resolves after a given amount of time.

Is there a canonical name for the `stall()` function?

Comment: I've never encountered such a canonical convention in the countless APIs I've encountered (this is a somewhat unusual requirement as well in my experience), but often I see what you're calling `minDuration` as `timeout` at least in synchronous/blocking contexts.

Comment: I agree it is a bit quirky. It was used in a web app that simply felt too fast.